# CD Free or dvd send for post mail

Tags: cd-drive

previously sent you a copy on cd or dvd software ubuntu. Would you like to know if you even send mail these cds or dvds? Thank you.
I from Guatemala

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I order or request an Ubuntu Installation CD or DVD?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/79715/where-can-i-order-or-request-an-ubuntu-installation-cd-or-dvd)

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are referring to Canonical's [ShipIt service](http://www.ubuntu.com/shipit). The service has been shut down since 2010. If you require Ubuntu, please [download it for free from the website.](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, [only LTS releases of Ubuntu will be sold on DVD through the Ubuntu Shop](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/canonical-ditching-ubuntu-cdsdvds-for-non-lts).

You can always, of course [download for free](http://www.ubuntu.com/download) and burn to a DVD or USB any Ubuntu (or derivates) release.