# New (computer-illiterate)Ubuntu user needs information

Tags: system-installation, laptop

I am in need of an operating system for my new laptop which was donated to me. I have NO idea how to download/work this computer. It will be used by my children for their school work mostly.

I don't have the internet at home except for on my cell phone, and I am still fuddling around with that on how to use it. In the directions online, it states to download Ubuntu onto a stick drive. Does this mean that I can download it on my cell phone and transfer it to the SD card and then use the SD card on the laptop to download the Ubuntu operating system?

Also, I do not have any internet at home, as I cannot afford it at this time. Is an operating system the same thing as the internet? Or do I have to find a free or discounted rate internet, for the laptop to work?

Thank you & God bless,

Comment: This question is unclear. Please, have a look at [how to ask](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips on how to improve your question. A good start would be to change the title in something which is a question. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I order or request an Ubuntu Installation CD or DVD?](http://askubuntu.com/q/79715/22949) or [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/q/6328/22949)

Answer (score 2):

**It is not possible to use just a cell phone to create an SD card that will install Ubuntu**

First, Not all laptops have SD card readers and even if yours have one, there is no guarantee that your laptop can boot from the SD card.

Second, downloading the file into an SD card using your phone is not enough. The card needs to be prepared using the downloaded file and other software so that your laptop can boot from the SD card. This is not possible using only a cell phone.

**Internet and the operating system are not the same thing**

Think of your laptop as a car. The operating system is the engine. The internet is all the paved roads in your country and beyond. You don't need the internet to enjoy your car. You can install an air-conditioner in the car. That would be a program in your laptop. Then you can turn the engine on and enjoy the cool air without going anywhere. Your children can turn on the lights, and honk the horn. You can drive it around in your yard, if you have a big yard. But if you have no engine in the car, the air-conditioner, lights, horn will not work. These are different programs in your laptop.

**What to do?**

If you really need to install Ubuntu in your laptop, you will need a working computer that is connected to the internet. This can be at your friend's home, at an internet cafe, or at a public library (depending on the country you live in). Then you will have to follow the instructions about how to prepare a Live-USB stick using the working computer. When that is ready you will have to follow the instructions about how to boot your laptop using the USB stick you have prepared. This is like changing or putting a new engine in a car. I suggest you read a lot before you try.

Alternately, go to a book store and find a book on Ubuntu. If possible leaf through the book to make sure that if has instructions for how to install Ubuntu. Some of the books include a DVD with Ubuntu in it. If you find one, you can use the DVD to install Ubuntu without the Internet.

Best of luck.